# $(this).#from_clicked_a

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#carousel a, #footer a').click(selectNav); // When any a-tag within divs with id="carousel" or id="footer" are clicked...
    // I want to indicate which pannel was slected in the carousel div by adding a css class to the coresponding a element within it.

    function selectNav() {
        $(this) // I may try stripping the url after the # and then use that...
            .parents('div:first') // I think I need to make sure this is pointing to the carousel div 
            // even when triggered by a link not within the carousel div(such as one from within the footer div for example)!
                .find('a') // I think this is then finding all "a"s within that div
                    .removeClass('selected') // then removes the css class "selected" from all a-tags
                .end() //
            .end() //
        .addClass('selected'); // and then adding the css class "selected" to the clicked on a-tag.
        //   or to the a tag id "#something" that was stripped from the url that corresponds...
        // So I need to instead of the above ".parents('div:first')"
        // replace that with something like "set the starting point to the fixed point of the div with id="carousel""
        // strip the class "selected" from all a tags within that div, and add back the class to the one I want... 
    }
});
```

If this helps my document structure lools like:

```
// body
//      div carousel (a-tags in here)
//      div controls2
//      ===== div scrollpanel
//      ______________ div scrollcontainer
//      ###################### children divs below scrllcontainer
//      ===== div footer (looks to me like its a sibling maybe of scrollpanel, and a child of controls2, which is a sibling of carousel)
```

Its not very important as I already have an indicator, but the code looks useful to me if I'm missing something very simple that can be added to get things to work...
    // can anyone help...

Comment: It would be helpful if you would separate the description of the issue from the code. I can't tell what is being asked.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a class to the parents that you can find later using [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/), like this:

```
$('#carousel a, #footer a').assClass('container').click(selectNav);
```

Then use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to go up to that `.container` element, overall like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#carousel a, #footer a').assClass('container').click(selectNav);

    function selectNav() {
        $(this).closest('.container').find('a').removeClass('selected')
               .end().end().addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

Or as an anonymous function:

```
$(function () {
  $('#carousel a, #footer a').assClass('container').click(function() {
     $(this).closest('.container').find('a').removeClass('selected')
            .end().end().addClass('selected');
  });
});
```